How do I solve this module not found error?
this is my first time using node and sass and I'm running into an error that I can't seem to shake off.
I'm trying to concat some .css files using this script (concat:css) but I'm always getting this 'module not found' error.
script & error
I've already removed all the modules, cleared the cache and reinstalled everything back up but the error doesn't stop happening. I also have the latest versions of Node and VS Code.
Any suggestions?
